# How does the drawContours function work in OpenCV when a contour is filled?

Tags: opencv

I was wondering what algorithm is used in OpenCV in the function cv2.drawContours (thickness <0; the contour shape is filled).

[drawContours documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#drawcontours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV's documents say that `cv::DrawContours` is based on scan-line polygon filling algorithm. `cv::DrawContours` mainly include two functions which named `CollectPolyEdges` and `FillEdgeCollection`. The former one is just collect edges based on some "key-points" achieved from contours. So `FillEdgeCollection` is used to fill these collections.

Here you have two example about the algorithm:

- [scan-line algorithm #1](http://www.comp.hkbu.edu.hk/~comp3080/2011/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Comp3080_L05_supp.pdf)
- [scan-line algorithm #2](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~icss571/filling/how_to.html)

For more information you can analyze the source of OpenCV's `cvDrawContours`:

- [`cv::CollectPolyEdges`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp#L2310)
- [`cv::FillEdgeCollection`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp#L2342)